# tomcat server web page issue

Tags: java, tomcat

I have installed tomcat server with java application in ubuntu 15.10. Tomcat server with Application is running in server (locally). But issue is that it is not running in other system browser (Remotely). I tried all ways like port changes, SSL config, server.xml config, web.xml. Please let me know what is the solution exactly.

I have attached the below remote tomcat web page error...

> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at
>   xxx.xxx.x.x:8080.
>
> The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a
>   few moments. If you are unable to load any pages, check your
>   computer's network connection. If your computer or network is
>   protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted
>   to access the Web.

Comment: Might be a firewall issue. check your servers firewall configurations and allow port 8080 connections

Comment: Have you configured an Apache server correctly?